# Use Totem's decoder to re-encode video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, totem

I recorded an OGV screencast in GTK-RecordMyDesktop that seems to play back differently in different players (and YouTube doesn't seem to understand the video stream at all -- it just displays  a green blob). When I try to use `ffmpeg` to transcode the OGV to OGV the video races to the last frame in the first few milliseconds. However, Totem plays the video back fine.

So, my question is: is there a way to use the Totem decoder (which I know understands the OGV file properly) to transcode the video through `ffmpeg`? That would presumably repair it. Thanks!

Comment: Thou shall not transcode as it is a sin to do so!

Comment: Well... I'm trying to make something that I can upload to YouTube. Tryeth as I might, surely avoidance of excessive bandwidth usage is not a sin?

Comment: No, uploading low-quality transcoded videos with visual and aural distortion is a sin. Spend some time to upload high quality content and others will be thankful.

Answer (score 2):

I installed Transmageddon and it was able to transcode to a WebM video that I could upload through YouTube. I guess Transmageddon uses the same codec set that Totem does. (GStreamer?)

Comment: GStreamer is a multimedia framework, not a codec.